# nginx - etag is not appearing whilst config tells him so

Tags: server, nginx

I'm currently optimizing a Dockerized Nginx 1.13 server and trying to add etags to the headers of an image.

My setting is the following:

```
  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'must-revalidate';
    expires 1y;
    etag on;
    gzip off;
    access_log off;
  }
```

And this is the servers response:

```
$ curl -I 127.0.0.1/example.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 11:21:45 GMT
Expires: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 22:32:58 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, must-revalidate
X-Cache-ESI: No
Content-Length: 10413
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 12 Jul 2017 22:32:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache-Status: MISS
```

So the question in charge is: why is the `etag` missing? It should be there.

Comment: I presume you made the change and then reloaded your nginx configuration?

Comment: I use Docker for it, so I need to rebuild everything which creates a new container (thus getting the new conf). You cannot "reload" nginx otherwise afaik in Docker.

Comment: Put that in your question.  The fact that you're using a Dockerized nginx 1.13 means that you're going to be running into some potential issues if it's not updated.  That, and it's *not* the same as optimizing standard baremetal nginx instances.